# Convolution with Landau kernel $L_k$ is polynomial of degree at most k

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, convolution, weierstrass-approximation

Let $B=B_\frac{1}{2}(0) \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that given a function $F \in C_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, with supp $F \subset B$ that the convolution $F \ast L_k$ restricted on $B$ is a polynomial of degree at most $k$.

My definition of the Landau kernel is $L_k: \mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$,
$$
L_k(x)=\frac{1}{c^n_k} \prod_{i=1}^n (1-x_{i}^2)^k 1_{[-1,1]^n}(x), \quad \text{ where } \quad c_k = \int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^kdt, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

I have already gotten to

$$
(F \ast L_k)(x) = \int_{\text{supp }F} F(y)L_k(y-x)dy,
$$

but seem to be stuck here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Just keep writing things out. Using your definition of $L_k$, we get that

\begin{align}
F \ast L_k(x) & = \int_{supp F} F(y) \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - (x_i - y_i)^2)^k dy 
\end{align}

You can use binomial theorem to deal with $(1-(x_i - y_i)^2)^k $. The details are tedious but you get a linear combination of powers of $x_i$ with coffecients being integrals with respect to $y$.

E.g if the dimension $n=1$, we get that

\begin{align}
F \ast L_k (x)& = \int_{supp F} F(y) (1-(x-y)^2)^k dy\\
& = \int_{suppF}F(y) \sum_{m=0}^k -1^{k} \binom{k}{m}(x-y)^{2m} dy\\
& \vdots \\
& \text{More details (i.e now expand the} (x-y)^{2m}  \text{and take}  \ x \  \text{out of the integral} ) \\
 & \vdots \\
& = \sum_{i = 0}^{2k} x^i\int_{supp F} F(y) g_i(y) dy
\end{align}

where $g_i(y)$ is some polynomial in the variable $y$. Therefore the integrals become coefficients for $x^i$ giving us that $F \ast L_k  $ is a polynomial of degree $2k$ (this is true regardless of the support of $F \ast L_k $).

Comment: This also means that your claim is wrong about it being degree $k$. But is a polynomial with degree related to $k$.